# Can't get Text Box to Update With new data

Tags: winforms, powershell

Working on my first form for PowerShell. At the top of the form is a ReadOnly textbox that shows the Hostname, Serial Number, IP Address, and MAC address for the machine it's being used on. I have a button below it to Refresh this data which will update to reflect current network connection (it's supposed to tell you if it's on WiFi, Ethernet, or disconnected and update the text box accordingly) As far as I can tell, it works! Except when media is disconnected. Then it doesn't change at all, it just keeps the same data.
I'm using Powershell Studio to make the Form but I get the same results when using a Form built with POSH.

When running this in a normal PS1 script using the console as the output, it works perfectly! Showing "Disconnected" for IP Address and MAC.

```
#The form's 'Shown' Event and the Refresh Button trigger this function
$UpdateSysInfo={
    $MHN = hostname
    $MSN = gwmi win32_bios | Select –ExpandProperty SerialNumber
    $MYIPAddress = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($MHN).AddressList[0]).IpAddressToString
    $MYIPMAC = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $MHN
    $MYMAC = ($MYIPMAC | where { $_.IpAddress -eq $MYIPAddress }).MACAddress

    $wifi = netsh interface show interface | findstr /C:"Wi-Fi" /C:"Name"

    if ($wifi -like '*Connected*')
    {
        $WiFi = "(Wi-Fi)"
    }
    Else
    {
        $WiFi = "(Ethernet)"
    }
    if ($WiFi -like '*(Wi-Fi)*')
    {
        $MACWiFi = "(Wi-Fi)"
    }
    Else
    {
        $MACWiFi = ""
    }

#If media is disconnected, then $MYIPAddress will be 127.0.0.1
    if ($MYIPAddress -like '127.0.0.1')
    {
        $ShowIP = "DISCONNECTED"
        $ShowMAC = "DISCONNECTED"
    }
    Else
    {
        $ShowIP = "$MYIPAddress $WiFi"
        $ShowMAC = "$MYMAC $MACWiFi"
#Should be pretty obvious, SysInfo is the Textbox where it's showing the accumulated data here
        $SysInfo.text = "Hostname: $MHN │ Serial Number: $MSN │ IP Address: $ShowIP │ MAC Address: $ShowMAC"
    }
}
```

No error messages. It works perfectly when connected to internet, but when network connection is disabled and it's supposed to show "Disconnected" it does not update the textbox to show that. As far as the info in that box is concerned, the network connection never changed. This is the case no matter how long I wait after disabling the network connection.

Comment: Maybe moving `$SysInfo.text = …` somewhere under (_below_?) the closing `}` of the ´if {} else {}´?

Answer (score 0):

`if ($wifi -like '*Connected*')
    {
        $WiFi = "(Wi-Fi)"
    }`

Is true for both "connected" and "disconnected"
and will always return `$WiFi = "(Wi-Fi)"`